# How I get data by group User ID for foreach controller function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I get data by grouping `user_id` for a foreach loop in a controller's function in Laravel. For example, `user_id = 2`, 5 rows available, `user_id = 1`, 10 rows available. Then show 2 arrays.

```
$lists = lists::wherestatus(1)->groupby('user_id')->get();

foreach($lists as $list){
   $list = functionHere;
}
```

What function can I create for this on the controller for grouping?

Answer (score 0):

I need more information, but based on what you shared, you should be able to do this (removing the `foreach`):

```php
$lists = Lists::whereStatus(1)->get()->groupBy('user_id');
```

The difference is that if you use `groupBy` before `get`, you are grouping your query by `user_id`, so instead of getting 5 rows for `user_id = 2` and 10 for `user_id = 1`, you are going to get 2 rows and just the latest data, so you need to use [Collection's `groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby).

What you want to do is group all the information by `user_id` but have each row, a schema like this:

```php
[
    '1' => [ // user_id
        ['user_id' => '1', 'column1' => 'random value'],
        ['user_id' => '1', 'column1' => 'other value'],
        // 8 remaining rows
    ],
    '2' => [ // user_id
        ['user_id' => '2', 'column1' => 'other nice value'],
        // 4 remaining rows
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should first in List model set:

> public function scopeStatus(){
>
> ```
>     return $this->where('status','1');
>
> }
> ```

and in your controller:

> $products = List::status()->groupby('user_id')->get();